# iPhone Crash Logs... anyone read this Greek Stuff? - Not crashing for me, but is for Apple

Tags: iphone, crash, store, logging

I have submitted my app to the App Store, and Apple says:

At this time, XYZ APP cannot be posted to the App Store because it is crashing on iPhone 3G running iPhone OS 3.1 and iPod touch running iPhone OS 3.1.1 and Mac OS X 10.5.8 whenever a user attempts to add a reminder from their Contacts.  There are two ways to reproduce this issue:

1) Launch XYZ APP
2) Log in
3) Select "Add New Reminder from Contacts"
4) Select a contact
5) XYZ APP crashes

First, this NEVER happens to me within the simulator or on an iPhone 3GS (don't have a 3G or iTouch).

The crash logs are basically in Greek.

Uploaded the logs here: http://www.megaupload.com/?d=9O408OSL

Any thoughts or comments would be appreciated.

Comment: please put a small sample in your question.

Comment: Crashes usually come about from releasing or accessing an object that no longer exists, or from calling a method that doesn't exist. Apple told you how they can reproduce this bug, so look at the parts of your code where you are initializing, allocating and releasing objects specific to the path Apple took to cause your app to crash.

Answer (score 2):

That you can't reproduce the issue just means that your runtime environment is different than Apple's test environment.   Did you try with/without WiFi connectivity?

Given that you have only tested on a 3GS, it may likely be a memory related issue. Namely, the 3GS has more memory than previous phones.  Are you leaking somewhere?

In any case, I would recommend getting a used older iPod Touch for testing purposes (or an 8GB of the current model, I think).

Finally, the crash logs are gibberish because they need to be symbolicated.

There is a ton of information available on doing exactly that.  See:

[Symbolicate iPhone Crash Logs](http://www.google.com/search?q=symbolicate+iphone+crash)

Answer (score 1):

You might want to start with a tutorial on [reading crash logs](http://reviews.cnet.com/8301-13727_7-10330727-263.html), this may help de-Greek it.

In short, it looks like your application is crashing in Thread #0 right after doing some Address Book stuff, which looks like Apple has pointed you on the right track.

You might want to use a debugger and walk through the code with the symbols resolved.

My guess is that you're getting a [SIGABRT](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SIGABRT) because you've freed something twice when you shouldn't have.

Comment: Probably not.  If it works on a 3GS & simulator, but not on anything else, this sounds much more like a different kind of crash.  Memory corruption or the like.  It doesn't necessarily sound like an over-release (though it could be that).  First things first is to symbolicate the crash logs.